# Match variable, then get single value from Mysql via Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I have never worked with Perl before, but one old script needed some changes (and is now becoming a burden to deal with).

Scenario:

Pushing text to script STDIN

**./myscript.pl < text**

The text has the following lines (among others):

```
...
To: "" <myemail@domain.com>
...
Type *123 to access this file.
...
```

What I need to do is to assign myemail@domain.com to variable1, assign 123 to variable2, and then do a MySQL select that will return variable3 based on the previous two.

I have:

```
$line = <>;
    my ($email) = ($line =~ m/To: ".*" <(.*)>/);
    my ($num) =  ($line =~ m/*.\*(\d+) .*$);


    #Connect to the database
    my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:dbase:localhost:3306', 'dbun', 'dbpass')
        or die "Couldn't open database: $DBI::errstr; stopped";

    # Fetch each row and print it
    my ($enabled) = $dbh->selectrow_array(SELECT myfield FROM mydb WHERE mynum = "$num" and email = "$email");

    # Disconnect from the database
    $dbh->disconnect();

    if($enabled eq "no") {
    die "Not enabled";
    }
...
```

Yet this does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update**

**Here is what I have after the revisions mentioned. The variable is successfully obtained from the database, but I cannot exit the script if "enabled" is set to "no". For some reason the query is looping.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

open(STDOUT, '>', '/var/log/vm/vm2email.out') or die "Can't open log";
open(STDERR, '>', '/var/log/vm/vm2email.log') or die "Can't open log";

open(VOICEMAIL,"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
open(LAMEDEC,"|/usr/bin/dos2unix|/usr/bin/base64 -di|/usr/bin/lame --quiet --preset voice - /var/spool/asterisk/tmp/vmout.$$.mp3");
open(VM,">/var/spool/asterisk/tmp/vmout.debug.txt"); 
my $inaudio = 0;

my $email;
my $ext;

loop: while(<>){
    if(/^\.$/){
    last loop;
    }
    if(/^Content-Type: audio\/x-wav/i){
    $inaudio = 1;
    }
    if (/To: ".*" <(.*)>/ ) {
    $email = $1;
    print "$email\n";
    }
    if (/\*(\d+) / ) {
    $ext = $1;
    print "$ext\n";
    }


    if ( $email && $ext ) {
    # Connect to the database
    $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:mydb:localhost:3306', 'dbun', 'dbpass')
    || die "Couldn't open database: $DBI::errstr; stopped";
    $enabled = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT sendvoicemail FROM data_voicemail WHERE vmbox = ? and email = ?', {}, $ext, $email)
    || die "Couldn't get DB value, stopped";
    }

    if ($enabled eq "no"){
    last;
    }


  if($inaudio){
    while(s/^(Content-.*)wav(.*)$/$1mp3$2/gi){}
    if(/^\n$/){
      iloop: while(<>){
        print LAMEDEC $_;
        if(/^\n$/){
          last iloop;
        }
      }
      close(LAMEDEC);
      print VOICEMAIL "\n";
      print VM "\n";
      open(B64,"/usr/bin/base64 /var/spool/asterisk/tmp/vmout.$$.mp3|");
      while(<B64>){
        print VOICEMAIL $_; 
    print VM $_;    
      }
      close(B64);
      print VOICEMAIL "\n";
      print VM "\n";
      $inaudio = 0;
    }

  }

 print VOICEMAIL $_;
 print VM $_;

}


print VOICEMAIL "\.";
print VM "\.";
close(VOICEMAIL);
close(VM);
```

Comment: The regular expression you assign `$num` from looks wrong.  The first `*` isn't following anything and it's missing an ending `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what's going wrong.

I do see that you aren't quoting your sql string, which would result in a syntax error; try

```
my ($enabled) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT myfield FROM mydb WHERE mynum = "$num" and email = "$email"');
```

though you should avoid putting user input directly into sql and use placeholders instead:

```
my ($enabled) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT myfield FROM mydb WHERE mynum = ? and email = ?', {}, $num, $email);
```

You also have three problems where you try to extract the values.

First, you aren't verifying that the regexes succeeded before trying to use the values you got.

Second, the `$num` regex is wrong.  I think you mean to be doing `/.*\*(\d+) .*$/`, but `/\*(\d+)/` would be a simpler regex that does exactly the same thing.

Third, if the values you want are on separate lines, you need to extract them one at a time in a loop:

```
my $email;
my $num;
while ( my $line = <> ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/To: ".*" <(.*)>/ ) {
        $email = $1;
    }
    if ( $line =~ /\*(\d+) / ) {
        $num = $1;
    }
}
if ( $email && $num ) {
    # database query here
}
```

(unless you read in the whole file as a single string).

Comment: Thanks! Works great, I can successfully get those variables and pull the field from DB. However, it seems like it somehow tampers with stdin, as I get: postfix/sendmail[25105]: fatal: root(0): No recipient addresses found in message header

Comment: um, it reads from `<>`; if no command line filenames are given, that will be stdin.

Comment: I have added the full script. It still not functioning as expected, unfortunately. Would appreciate your feedback!

Comment: is it doing the database query?  if so, what is $enabled (from what you say it sounds as if it is something true (or you would have died with "Couldn't get db value...") but not eq "no").  if not, is $ext getting set?  is $email?

Comment: We get $enabled from the database. It can be either "yes" or "no". I did try to print it, and it is getting it properly. The issue is, I can only call it from inside the loop (since I am parsing $ext/vmbox and $email from stdin) and thus 1) I get repeated output for even 1 print 2) I cannot exit the script